# What happens to a multiclass character affected by level drain?

Tags: multi-classing, undead, adnd-1e, character-levels

Suppose I have a halfling that's multiclassing as a fighter/thief and has achieved 2nd level in both classes. This character has the misfortune of being struck by a wight and loses a level.

What happens here? Is the character now level 1/1, or do they become a level 1 fighter and a level 2 thief? If they lose a level in only one class, how do you determine which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The character loses a level from the Fighter class

> A multi-classed character (or character with two classes) who is drained of
> an experience level always loses the highest level he or she has gained
> (e.g., a halfling 2nd level fighter/3rd level thief would lose one level of
> thieving ability). If all levels are equal, the highest level of the class which
> requires the greatest amount of experience points is lost. If a multi-classed
> character (e.g., a fighter/magic-user) is struck by a creature which drains
> two levels, a level is drained from each class.

DMG p. 119